# VQmod not working for open cart admin

Tags: migration, opencart, server, vqmod

I am having the most frustrating issue with VQmod. I moved my OpenCart store from a Godaddy VPS to Rackspace's Cloud Sites. The move went fine and everything works properly except the VQmod's on the admin panel.  None of them load. No errors in the log files, no admin cache files in the cache dir, no php errors.

Things I have tried:

- Cleared all cache Changed admin folder to 755
- reinstalled VQmod tried both manually and using the installer with fresh index.php files
- Removed all XML files and tried to load only one at a time
- Cursed loudly at my computer repeatedly.

Please Help! OC version 1.5.6 VQmod 2.5.1

Comment: Did you ask this question here? http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=137804

Comment: Jay, I did ask that question. Im going on two days now that our site has been down. Since we use the admin mods to produce and process every order that comes in. all of my employees have just been sitting around waiting for me to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those that want the solution to this, the issue was that the `config.php` files were both using relative paths instead of the full paths for OpenCart's various directories. They should always be full paths, or resolved with `realpath()` in the config.php files themselves

Comment: In my case it wasn't. As of now, the [vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Troubleshooting](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Troubleshooting) article doesn't make it obvious the `mods.cache` and `checked.cache` files should be deleted. I would contribute a change but I can't see the "Edit" button on that page, even though I'm logged in.

Comment: @TheSexiestManinJamaica I've just added a line about deleting the `mods.cache`. Deleting `checked.cache` isn't necessary. This will refresh any time the `mods.cache` file changes

Comment: Watch for case in the paths! The actual path had an uppercase in a folder name, while the config (manually built) had all lowercase - was very difficult to find!

Answer (score 2):

My case was a bit different. I checked the permissions, paths, all the regular stuff that comes to mind first. I even walked step by step through [the manual installation guide](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart#how-to-install-manually).

The Opencart copy in question is shared across several environments using git. Long story short, the `mods.cache` and `checked.cache` were not added to .gitignore right away, and when I finally did that, I emptied both of them just to make sure Opencart will write new content based on my current environment. Turns out, since `mods.cache` was empty, Opencart believed there are no mods available.

**Solution**: delete both `vqmod/mods.cache` and `vqmod/checked.cache`.

**Update**: here are some similar issues:

- https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/issues/32
- https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/issues/3

The [vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Troubleshooting](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Troubleshooting) guide, as of now, does not make it obvious the files should've been deleted, neither does the [vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart), and there doesn't seem to be any way to contirbute. vQmod fails silently, without producing any notifications, warnings, or simply detecting the issue and rebuilding the cache files. I've spent few hours trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Always fun to google my own answers. Thanks, 2016 me, you saved 2020 me those few hours. Wish I could upvote :D

Comment: Thanks, By deleting both files it worked for me.