# vQmod not working on Opencart 3

Tags: opencart, vqmod, opencart-3

Opencart 3 has released but seems vQmod cannot working.
Its deprecated, right?
Or What can I need to do it work? Please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VQmod not working for open cart admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159373/vqmod-not-working-for-open-cart-admin)

Comment: Just remember it's very early days for OpenCart 3 (as of June 2017), so the mod you're trying to install which uses vQmod may not yet have been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download the latest version (vqmod-2.6.2-opencart.zip).

**OpenCart integration of vQmod (v2.6.2-opencart)**

- Updated vqmod_opencart.xml to support OpenCart 3.0.0 twig template system (Thanks for the regex Jay!)
- Change IgnoreIf back to VQSearchNode to keep autotrim and remove need for open/close tags to be on the same line
- Added fix for case insensitivity in file paths

Download: https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/releases/tag/v2.6.2-opencart

Comment: Note for rookies: After uploading the vQmod files, remember to run the installer (go to http://yoursite.com/vqmod/install)

Answer (score -1):

After a little research it seems that there is some   changes needed for the new twig system.

You just need to download a new > vqmod_opencart.xml file that you can find [here](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/files/1092415/vqmod_opencart.txt) .
It is with .txt extension so just rename it to > vqmod_opencart.xml.

[here](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/issues/108) is the reference to the answer.

Hope it helps :)